# Populate an object and pass it in a request parameter in GraphQL

Tags: graphql, graphql-java

How can we populate an object and pass it in a request parameter in GraphQL. For example, i want to get rid of sequence of parameters here in the GraphQL request and want to create an object and pass it as a single parameter.

```
{
 allBooks(first:20, orderBy:"myRating"){
  isn
  title
  authors
  publisher
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [GraphQL Input Types](https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#input-types).

In your `schema` definition you need to define the input into something like:

```
input BooksInput {
  first: Int
  orderBy: String
}
```

And require it as the `args` type in your query, then use it as:

```
{
 allBooks($input: {first:20, orderBy:"myRating"}){
  isn
  title
  authors
  publisher
 }
}
```